# Using multiple features with scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working on text classification using scikit-learn.  Things work well with a single feature, but introducing multiple features is giving me errors.  I think the problem is that I'm not formatting the data in the way that the classifier expects.

For example, this works fine:

```
data = np.array(df['feature1'])
classes = label_encoder.transform(np.asarray(df['target']))
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data, classes)

classifier = Pipeline(...)

classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

But this:

```
data = np.array(df[['feature1', 'feature2']])
classes = label_encoder.transform(np.asarray(df['target']))
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data, classes)

classifier = Pipeline(...)

classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

dies with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jed/Dropbox/LegalMetric/LegalMetricML/motion_classifier.py", line 157, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 130, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._pre_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 120, in _pre_transform
    Xt = transform.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 780, in fit_transform
    vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 715, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 229, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 195, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

during the preprocessing stage after classifier.fit() is called.  I think the problem is that way I'm formatting the data, but I can't figure out how to get it right.

feature1 and feature2 are both English text strings, as is the target.  I'm using LabelEncoder() to encode target, which seems to work fine.

Here's an example of what `print data` returns, to give you a sense of how it's formatted right now.

```
[['some short english text'
  'a paragraph of english text']
 ['some more short english text'
  'a second paragraph of english text']
 ['some more short english text'
  'a third paragraph of english text']]
```

Comment: Well, how are you formatting the data?  I've generally found that I can just pass the pandas DataFrame directly to `scikit` functions and it works okay.

Comment: I tried passing the DataFrame directly to `train_test_split()` and I get the same error.
`train_test_split(df['feature1'], label_encoder.transform(df['target']))` works fine.

`train_test_split(df[['feature1', 'feature2']], label_encoder.transform(df['matches']))` doesn't.

Comment: Can you print out what `X_train` looks like in each of the two cases.

Comment: With two features `X_train` looks the same as the `print data` example in the question (not literally the same, since it was split, of course).  With one feature `X_train` looks like this:
`['short english text' 'additional english text'
 'more short english text' ..., 'still more short english text'
 'yet more short english text' 'english text']`

So with two features it's an array of arrays of strings and with one feature it's an array of strings.  Presumably that's the problem, but I don't know what `fit()` expects it to look like.

Comment: Looking at the documentation I knew that `fit()` expect an `{array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]`.  Printing `X_train.shape` with two features gives `(4630, 2)`.  With one feature it's `(4630,)`.  So that seems correct.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

The particular error message makes it seem like your code somewhere expects something to be a `str` (so that `.lower` may be called) but instead it is receiving a whole array (probably a whole array of `str`s).

Can you edit the question to better describe the data and also post the full traceback, not just the small part with the named error?

In the meantime, you can also try

```
data = df[['feature1', 'feature2']].values
```

and

```
df['target'].values
```

instead of explicitly casting to `np.ndarray` yourself.

It looks to me like an array is being made where it is 1x1 and the singleton element in the "array" is itself an `ndarray`.

Answer (score 1):

If your text columns have the same encoder / transformer, merge the columns together.

```
data = np.append(df.feature1. df.feature2)
```